# Adding the sum of labels from a table cell in Swift

Tags: swift, function, uitableview, sum, cell

I cannot figure this out since I do not know enough about table cells. I am building an invoice app for myself. In my tableview custom cell I made a label on the right side that is for amount due. when you fill out the invoice it prints out the amount in that label.

I have an empty label at the very top call totalDue that I want to have the sum of every amount in the table. I am struggling with this.

What I have is

```
import UIKit

var clientName = [String]()
var dueDate = [String]()
var projecDescript = [String]()
var dateStamp = Date()
var invoiceNum = [String]()
var amountDue = [String]()

var clientPicker = [""]





// Custom cell to make all input fields custom
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    //Make your outlets here, connect the outlets from cell in your storyboard

    @IBOutlet var clientNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var amountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var invoiceNum: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var dateStamp: UILabel!

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var clientTableList: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var totalDue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var totalBillsLabel: UILabel!


    func calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0

    for amount in amountDue {
    sum += amount
    }

    totalDue.text = "\(sum)"

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return (clientName.count)
        return (dueDate.count)
        return (projecDescript.count)
        return (invoiceNum.count)
        return (amountDue.count)

    }



    // This is the new items added into the inputs
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "clientCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        // Adds Clients Name
        let companyName = clientName[indexPath.row]
        cell.clientNameLabel?.text = companyName

        // Adds Clients Description
        let descriptionName = projecDescript[indexPath.row]
        cell.descriptionLabel?.text = descriptionName

        // Adds the amount due
        let amountName = amountDue[indexPath.row]
        cell.amountLabel?.text = "$\(amountName)"

        //Adds the total number of bills that you have in invoice
        totalBillsLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"

        //Adding sum of all bills
        sum += Int((amountName as NSString).floatValue)
        //sum = Int((amountName as NSString).floatValue)

        totalDue.text = "\(sum)"

        //Adds DueDate
        let invoiceDate = "Due \(dueDate[indexPath.row])"
        cell.dateLabel?.text = invoiceDate

        //Adds invoice Number
        let invoiceNum = "Invoice #BMCS \(indexPath.row + 1)"
        cell.invoiceNum.text = invoiceNum

        //TimeStamp in the label datestamp
        let timeStamp = "\(DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .short, timeStyle: .short))"
        cell.dateStamp?.text = timeStamp

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Edit") { (action, index) in

            //tableView.isEditing = true


            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditDetails", sender: self)
            }


            print("Edit Button Pressed")
        }

        editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Remove") { (action, indexPath) in
            //Remove the labels in the custom cell
            clientName.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            //dueDate.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            projecDescript.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            amountDue.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

            //minus one total bill when deleting one
            self.totalBillsLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row - 1)"
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                self.totalBillsLabel.text = "0"
            }



            self.clientTableList.reloadData()

        }

        let emailAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Email") { (action, index) in
            print("Email Button Pressed")
        }

        emailAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

        let phoneCallAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Call") { (action, index) in
            print("Call Button Pressed")
        }

        phoneCallAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue



        return [deleteAction,editAction,emailAction,phoneCallAction]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        clientTableList.reloadData()

    }




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Second controller

```
@IBAction func addInvoice(_ sender: Any) {


        if clientNameInput.text != "" && descriptionNameInput.text != ""  && amountInput.text != ""
        {
            clientName.append(clientNameInput.text!)
            //clientInput.text = ""

            projecDescript.append(descriptionNameInput.text!)
            //descriptionFieldInput.text = ""

            //dueDate.append(dateInput.text!)
            //dateInput.text = ""

            amountDue.append(amountInput.text!)
            //amountList.text = ""

            dueDate.append(newDueDateLabel.text!)


            // After hit send this is the button that takes you back without having to back out yourself
            _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }

    }
```

Comment: please show code for cellForRowAt method

Comment: just added the code for you to look at. Keep in mind that I am still new to swift so be nice please! :)

Comment: can you show me the screenshot of you tableview in simulator?

Comment: Ok good, declare var sum = 0 after this line @IBOutlet var totalDue: UILabel! , when you are done please tell me

Comment: did that. But my problem is that I am not writing the proper code to pull the amount due from each cell to add them together

Comment: Ok next do this: sum += Int((amountName as NSString).floatValue) in cellForRowAt method and tell me the result

Comment: okay now when I do that. I entered 54.00 as the mount and when I added invoice it doubled it.

Comment: Ok , so is your problem solved?

Comment: no sorry my bad... for example if I make an invoice for 54.00 and then a second for 23.00 it give me the total being 154.00. it is basically doubling both of them

Comment: please check kwdev's answer, actually he is talking right, if you still face problem please ask, if you have amountDue array full of values then you can simply make a function

Comment: if it is possible please show the complete controller class

Comment: yes one second...

Comment: Where are you adding amounts to amountDue array in your code?

Comment: just added at top... its in the second view controller

Comment: check my answer see if it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this

```
var clientName = [String]()
var dueDate = [String]()
var projecDescript = [String]()
var dateStamp = Date()
var invoiceNum = [String]()
var amountDue = [String]()
var sum = 0.0
```

remove sum from other places in your viewcontroller

then in your second view controller

after `amountDue.append(amountInput.text!)`

add this

```
sum += Double(amountInput.text!)!
```

then in your `ViewController`

add this

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                super.viewDidAppear(animated)
                totalDue.text = "\(sum)"
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much! The only problem I have now is that it crashes if I try to add 54.00 instead of just 54. Any reasons why? and what made this way do the magic trick?

Comment: @BlueMoose see my updated answer, replace Int with double, see if error is solved

Comment: it says this now...  Cannot convert value of type 'Double?' to expected argument type 'Int'

Comment: awesome it freakin works! your a life saver!!! so putting the answer in viewdidappear does what exactly?

Comment: @BlueMoose viewDidLoad is called only once when initially your viewcontroller is loaded and afterwords when you go to second viewcontroller and come back then other methods are called like viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear, these are called ViewControllerLifecycle methods, since viewDidAppears is called when you come back from secondviewcontroller so therefore we updated the label there, you can learn more by googling ViewControllerLifecycle

Comment: @BlueMoose and one more thing since you are beginner above code is "may be slightly"  acceptable, but in practise you should not declare global variables, since you have declared all arrays as global, which means that it is accessible to other viewcontrollers in your case secondviewcontroller, so I did the same with sum , I declared it as global , so change is through out your project, I would highly encourage you to visit raywenderlich.com and read the book by bignerdranch.com , they will tell you to use the proper design patterns of ios development

Comment: @BlueMoose no worries, glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Do not compute the total in cellForRowAt. That is called every time the row is made visible on the screen, so even if it were summing everything, it would be wrong. Create a separate function that computes the sum and return that to populate the label. Something like:

```
func calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0

    for amount in amountDue {
        sum+= Int(amount) // more practical to convert to float here
    }

    totalDue.text = "\(sum)"
}
```

Then call this method in your viewDidLoad and other appropriate places, such as after a new row is added.

Comment: this is now giving me the error.  Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'String' its probably because my amountDue is a string right now?

Comment: See my edit. Just wrap the amount inside Int as you were before. Just note that Int will always return a whole number. You probably really want to use a float here since it's currency.

Comment: that makes sense... what do I do about the line below, sum += Int((amountName as NSString).floatValue)

Comment: I did it just comes back blank